# How to start any device automatically after some time of SwitchOff like after 10 minutes?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to make a scheduler which will start any device if it goes switch off by anyhow. I know that `adb-reboot` can only can only restart a device and there are other commands too which can turn off a device but there is no such thing which can start a device.

The alarm service of android keep on running even after getting switched off that's why alarm rings up in switch off mode too but i have no idea how to improvise this thing to start a device. Can we make some scheduler to do so? There is this thread https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54260/what-is-an-alternate-way-to-switch-off-mobile-without-use-of-power-button and i have checked in various devices like that of Samsung, Mi, Motorola, etc but none of them is having an option to schedule a power on/off, maybe its removed now?

These commands are only for power off and will work only with rooted devices as said in this thread: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47989/how-can-i-shutdown-my-android-phone-using-an-adb-command

I need the android device to start after 10 minutes of getting powered off, Please help.

````
adb shell su -c 'am start -n android/com.android.internal.app.ShutdownActivity'  #alternative; the aforesaid intent is supposed to be passed to this component under normal circumstances, but calling the component alone works too
adb shell su -c 'svc power shutdown'```
````

Comment: Don't you think it's HORRIBLE that apps can automatically boot up a phone?

Comment: BigBrother and 1984 stuff would happen very quickly.

Comment: in all honesty @Zun, how do we know that doesn't exist already :D it's probably possible and happening already, we just don't know about it or don't have access to it...